# tensorflow module has no stack method

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm new to tensorflow: I have tf version 0.8 and cuda 7.5 this is my code:
my version of numpy is 1.11 i think(not sure)
how can I fix it? it say no module name stack??
I am trying to implement variational Autoencoder

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from libs.utils import weight_variable, bias_variable, montage_batch

def VAE(input_shape=[None, 784],
        n_components_encoder=2048,
        n_components_decoder=2048,
        n_hidden=2,
        debug=False):
    # %%
    # Input placeholder
    if debug:
        input_shape = [50, 784]
        x = tf.Variable(np.zeros((input_shape), dtype=np.float32))
    else:
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, input_shape)

    activation = tf.nn.softplus

    dims = x.get_shape().as_list()
    n_features = dims[1]

    W_enc1 = weight_variable([n_features, n_components_encoder])
    b_enc1 = bias_variable([n_components_encoder])
    h_enc1 = activation(tf.matmul(x, W_enc1) + b_enc1)

    W_enc2 = weight_variable([n_components_encoder, n_components_encoder])
    b_enc2 = bias_variable([n_components_encoder])
    h_enc2 = activation(tf.matmul(h_enc1, W_enc2) + b_enc2)

    W_log_sigma = weight_variable([n_components_encoder, n_hidden])
    b_log_sigma = bias_variable([n_hidden])

    z_mu = tf.matmul(h_enc3, W_mu) + b_mu
    z_log_sigma = 0.5 * (tf.matmul(h_enc3, W_log_sigma) + b_log_sigma)

    # %%
    # Sample from noise distribution p(eps) ~ N(0, 1)
    if debug:
        epsilon = tf.random_normal(
            [dims[0], n_hidden])
    else:
        epsilon = tf.random_normal(
            tf.stack([tf.shape(x)[0], n_hidden]))
```

and the log is :

```
  File "/home/hoda/Downloads/tensorflow_tutorials-master/python/11_variational_autoencoder.py", line 58, in VAE
    tf.stack([tf.shape(x)[0], n_hidden]))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stack'
```

Comment: _"it say no module name stack"_ - no it doesn't! The error is telling you that your `tensorflow` module has no `stack` method. The docs say that [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) does exist though - so you must be using too old a version

Comment: i am using tensorflow 0.8.0 bcz I have cuda7! which version should I installed bcz the latest only worl with cuda8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.stack` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/0ee63d0cdb63df0f34dada5176d6a5ad92fbccab), which github shows the earliest tag as version 0.12.0. Can you upgrade `tensorflow` to that version?

If not - it looks like `tensorflow` used to call this function `tf.pack`, so perhaps using that name instead will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `tf` docs.

`np.stack` is a relatively new function.  `hstack` and `vstack` have been around for along time, and are just wrappers for `np.concatenate`.  `np.stack` was added as a convenience to make `concatenate` on a new axis more flexible.  Look at its code with `np.source(np.stack)`.

Given that history, I wouldn't be surprised if `tf` doesn't have a similar function, or its a new one.  Or it could implemented independently of the `np.stack` model.